# Meteor: Deploying to Amazon EC2

Tags: mongodb, deployment, amazon-ec2, meteor

I am reading about [Deploying to EC2](http://julien-c.fr/2012/10/meteor-amazon-ec2/). The final step looks like this, where I put the bundle folder outside of my meteor project

```
PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/sidebar
ROOT_URL=http://ec2-23-20-113-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
sudo node ../bundle/main.js
```

where I replace the ROOT_URL with the public DNS shown in my AWS console. I am not quite sure what to use for MONGO_URL, so I start the meteor via the command

```
meteor
```

to see what the mongodb address meteor uses, which turns out to be

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
```

But for the node app to be able to connect to mongodb, I have to keep the meteor app running. When it seems to be working, with the console showing

```
listening
```

I try to access the site using the public DNS, but it doesn't work. So I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to try a different approach that runs in production as intended (via meteor bundle): https://github.com/matb33/meteor-ec2-install

Comment: In using that script, would MONGO_URL still be mongodb://127.0.0.1:3002/meteor?

Comment: Almost. Port 27017 instead of 3002.

Comment: You may also find the Meteor-UP project useful: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

This article also has examples of setting up load balancing with HAProxy: http://meteorhacks.com/how-to-scale-meteor.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I saw the command "mup deploy" somewhere before not knowing what it meant; now I know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start your own instance of mongodb. What you are seeing when running your project using the `meteor` command is just the in-place mongo db that meteor provides you with for development. In production you just start your own mongodb (install it via your linux package manager) and then set your `MONGO_URL` to that -- you can use the local IP for that.

On Ubuntu on AWS, for instance, if you installed mongodb using `apt-get install mongodb`, it will run on this URL: `MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdbname'`. If you use a separate AWS instance to run the db then you'll just replace `localhost` with the IP of that instance.

BTW: you should avoid running anything as root, incl. your bundled app. I'm assuming you are doing that only in order to be able to bind to port 80. A perhaps safer way of doing so is to allow your user to bind to that port also using the following command prior to invoking node:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/bin/nodejs
```

**Update:**
The easiest way to set these environment variables is to just use `env`:

```
sudo env PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/sidebar ROOT_URL=http://ec2-23-20-113-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ node ../bundle/main.js
```

Comment: I first run sudo mongod --smallfiles and then start the node app with MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor but still get Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment

Comment: Thanks. There is no error now (just blank); but my browser says that it cannot connect to that address when I visit the ROOT_URL. I can't think of what's missing.

Comment: are you sure that url is a valid public url, and not internal to AWS? have you tried the IP of your instance?

Comment: The address is correct. It turns out I need to change the security setting to allow inbound http and then wait for a few minutes.